# Rotating Banners

Tags: javascript, rotation

Having some trouble with rotating images. I am using the following code.

```
<div style="float: right;">
    <div id="main_rotate">
        <script>
            var Banners = new Array('images/course4.jpg', 'images/dRange3.jpg', 'images/cHouse2.jpg', 'images/course1.png');
            var CurrentBanner = 0;
            function DisplayBanners() {
                if (document.images) {
                    CurrentBanner++
                    if (CurrentBanner == Banners.length) {
                        CurrentBanner = 0;
                    }
                    document.RotateBanner.src=Banners[CurrentBanner];
                    setTimeout("DisplayBanners()",2000);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <p>
            <img src="images/course4.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" name="RotateBanner" border="0" alt="banner" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp</div>
    <div id="main_rotate">
        <script>
            var Banners1 = new Array('images/backSpin250x250.jpg', 'images/dimples250x250.jpg', 'images/phantomGolf250x250.jpg', 'images/tiiger250x250.jpg', 'images/zang250x250.jpg');
            var CurrentBanner1 = 0;
            function DisplaySponsors() {
                if (document.images) {
                    CurrentBanner1++
                    if (CurrentBanner1 == Banners1.length) {
                        CurrentBanner1 = 0;
                    }
                    document.RotateBanner1.src = Banners1[CurrentBanner1];
                    setTimeout("DisplaySponsors()", 2100);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <p>
            <img src="images/backSpin250x250.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" name="RotateBanner1" border="0" alt="banner" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this works fine on the home page, does exactly what it's meant to do, but when I use it on another page only the first banner works. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue? The second page will have six rotating spots in total so also open to other ideas if doing it rather than this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check document.images is initialized in the second page? Or that you are calling the function?

Comment: As far as other ideas go, if you are making a lot of animations, carousels, etc, you should look at jQuery as a solution.

Comment: both pages have include header and on the header i have onload= each function.